# Second initialization of WorkManager

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, dagger-2, android-workmanager

I have to initialize WorkerManager not only once because at Runtime some arguments may change (WorkerFactory()). So I need to call

```
val configuration = Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(aggregatingWorkerFactory)
            .build()

WorkManager.initialize(context!!, configuration)
```

However, calling it second time throws IllegalStateException.

I read that I can initialize it on ContentProvider:
https://medium.com/@programmerr47/custom-work-manager-initialization-efdd2afa6459 
but my workerFactory object is injected by dagger and I couldn't use AndroidInjector on Content Provider, because it was always not initialized:

> Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property androidInjector has not been initialized

I read [here](https://medium.com/@pedro.henrique.okawa/content-providers-dependency-injection-dagger-2-4ee3e49777b) that there is an interface `HasContentProviderInjector`:
but I cannot find it in my Dagger2 version 2.24 and I don't believe it should work, because If I understand correctly ContentProvider is created before Application object.

What should I do? Try to clear by reflection objects:
`sDelegatedInstance != null && sDefaultInstance != null`
or sth else?

Comment: What is the use case to have different configurations?

Comment: A/B tests and business logic.

Comment: What do you mean with Business Logic? Which configuration do you want to change?

Comment: Hi @dudeck, Did you find a solution for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WorkManager is a singleton and it can only be initialized once.
You can have the default initialization or your own initialization. To have your own configuration you need to disable the default one as described [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration).